# what's the best javascript UI framework integrated with ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, javascript, javascript-framework

What's the best JavaScript UI framework integrated with ASP.NET MVC 3?

jQuery is a must library now, and...
for UI framework, I have tried www.jqwidgets.com, jquery easy ui
now i am looking at KendoUI...

my expectation is, the UI framework should be a plus, the content(elements) will be generated by asp.net MVC, and the UI framework would make UI better, more friendly, more nice.

Comment: jqueryUI? thats normally what i use

Comment: I agree with Luke. Check out [jqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the jQuery UI Extensions for MVC. See here: http://jmvcui.codeplex.com/